# Postman Error: Value is not a valid byteString

Tags: web-services, post, postman

I am trying to invoke a POST web service via Postman and I am getting the following error.

> Error while sending request: Failed to execute `setRequestHeader` on
>   `XMLHttpRequest`: Value is not a valid ByteString.

**Request Headers**

```
X-PW-AccessToken:{{api_token}}
X-PW-Application:developer_api
X-PW-UserEmail:{{api_email}}
Content-Type:application/json
```

**Request Body**

```
{
  "page_size": 25
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error, and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: What does the request look like in Postman?

Comment: @DannyDainton I have updated the request structure to Question

Answer (score 1):

I think Http protocol's header can only post ByteString (what is ByteString? I think it is ASCII).

So if you have other char, for example, 汉字. if you put '汉字' add to Http Header the error 'Value is not a valid ByteString' happen!

Solove: You can use the `encodeURI` function to encode the String in the client, and then, You can use `URLdecode.decode()(java)` to decode the header information in the server.